# ConcurrentModification error due to an enhanced for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

The below code is causing an `Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` error.

I am trying to use an enhanced for loop to iterate through my drones ArrayList to update their position and directions. The following code works for only 1 drone in the ArrayList.

`tryToMove()` takes the direction of the drone, moves it into the corresponding x,y and checks if its valid, if it is not it changes direction.

`doDisplay()` prints the arena with the drones in the console.

```
public static void moveAllDrones(){
    String strOfCurrentDirection;
    Direction currentDirection;
        
    for (String drone : drones) {
        id = drones.indexOf(drone);
        System.out.println("Working on drone: " + id);
        String[] coords = drone.split(",");
        accX = Integer.parseInt(coords[0]);//get x coordinate
        accY = Integer.parseInt(coords[1]);// get y coordinate
            
        String droneWithCurrentID = drones.get(id); //direction in string
        strOfCurrentDirection = droneWithCurrentID.split(",")[2];
        currentDirection = Direction.valueOf(strOfCurrentDirection); //convert string to direction
            
            
        Drone.tryToMove(id, currentDirection, accX, accY);
    }
    DroneInterface.doDisplay();
}
```

I am not sure why this enhanced for loop only works for 1 drone.
Any help is appreciated thanks.

update:

```
public static void tryToMove(int id2, Direction accDir, int x1, int y1) {
        xPos = x1;
        yPos = y1;
        //Direction d = Drone.direction; // get current direction drone is facing.
        System.out.println("Trying to move drone, "+id2+ ". In the direction of: "+accDir);
        switch (accDir) {

        case NORTH: 
            yPos -= 1;
            if (DroneArena.canMoveHere(xPos, yPos)) {

                DroneArena.yRan = yPos;
                
            } else {
                yPos += 1;
                accDir = Direction.nextDirection();
            }
            DroneArena.updateDrone(id2, accDir, xPos, yPos);
            break;
        case EAST:

            xPos += 1;
            if (DroneArena.canMoveHere(xPos, yPos)) {

                DroneArena.xRan = xPos;


            } else {
                xPos -= 1;
                accDir = Direction.nextDirection();
            }
            DroneArena.updateDrone(id2, accDir, xPos, yPos);
            break;
        case SOUTH:

            yPos += 1;
            if (DroneArena.canMoveHere(xPos, yPos)) {
                DroneArena.yRan = yPos;

            } else {
                yPos -= 1;
                accDir = Direction.nextDirection();
            }
            DroneArena.updateDrone(id2, accDir, xPos, yPos);
            break;
        case WEST:

            xPos -= 1;
            if (DroneArena.canMoveHere(xPos, yPos)) {

                DroneArena.xRan = xPos;

            } else {
                xPos += 1;
                accDir = Direction.nextDirection();
            }
            DroneArena.updateDrone(id2, accDir, xPos, yPos);
            break;

        }
    }
```

update drone:

```
public static void updateDrone(int id2, Direction direction, int newX, int newY){

        updatedDirection = direction;
        DroneArena.direction = updatedDirection;
        drones.remove(id2);
        drones.add(id2, newX + "," + newY +"," + updatedDirection);

    }
```

Comment: A `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown when you modify a collection while iterating over it. The code that you show doesn't modify the `drones` collection, so the reason why the `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown must be within `Drone.tryToMove()`

Comment: Does `Drone.tryToMove()` modify any of the Strings in `drones`?  We will need to see that method, too, in order to help you.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong `tryToMove() calls updateDrone() which removes the arrayList with the corresponding id and then adds a new element to the list with the same id but new values

Comment: @ThomasKläger ill update the question to show that method

Comment: Well there you go, you modify the ArrayList while iterating on it.  [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) is the relevant documentation.  I found it by googling "Java ConcurrentModificationException".  If it wasn't so taboo on StackOverflow, I would post an LMGTFY link.

Comment: You could replace `drones.remove(id2); drones.add(id2, newX + "," + newY +"," + updatedDirection);` with `drones.set(id2, newX + "," + newY +"," + updatedDirection);`, which would also remove the `ConcurrentModificationException` because it doesn't do the remove/add (which leads to the CME), but has same effect (replacing the value at the position id2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoModEx means one thing, and one thing only:

1. You create an iterator I off of collection C (and `for (T a : c)` is creating an iterator of `c`).
2. At some later point in time, collection C is modified somehow (and not via the `.remove()` method of iterator I).
3. You interact in any way with I: Call any method in it, or hit the `for (T a : c)` loop (you get to the end of the loop, or run `continue;` in the loop.

You're doing that here: you make an iterator of `drones` when you start your for loop, and you modify `drones`, and then you iterate the loop (because `tryToMove` modifies drones).

You just can't do that, and it should be obvious why: What does that even mean? If you iterate over `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and during the iteration of `2`, you remove `3`, should 3 then just be skipped? What if during the iteration of `2`, you remove `1`? If 3 should be skipped, but 1 is already completed and cannot be skipped, what does that mean? Separately, trying to keep track of what has been removed is non-trivial (normally you'd just use an index, but if you start deleting earlier elements halfway through the loop, that becomes tricky) which is a second reason for why this works the way it does: You **cannot modify** a collection while you are iterating through it. Period.

So, how do you solve it?

The easy way is to first make a copy of drones, and then iterate through the copy. This way, any modifications you make during the loop don't affect your copy, and thus do not cause CoModExes. Note that this of course means none of the modifications you are making are visible during the loop.

A second option, which applies only to arraylists or other constructs with fast index-based lookup, is to use an old style for-loop, and manually managing the index variable.

A third is to use collection types with explicitly defined behaviour for this (such as `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, which does the first option built into the list itself.

A fourth is to redesign what you are doing such that modifying the underlying collection is no longer a part of it.

A fifth is to store all operations you'd like to do to your list during iteration, and then apply them all afterwards.

There are a billion more - it depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: How would I be able to change this into the standard for loop? I am too far along to redesign the approach as my deadline is very near unfortunately. thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: Changing ArrayList to CopyOnWriteArrayList sorted it... thanks for the help!